# Comparing Date pickers within cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am using material UI Date Pickers, within my project there are several date field inputs, a startDate and a endDate are my examples, using cypress I need to compare the data input between 2 date pickers, so for instance comparing EndDate with startDate, an example would be endDate cannot be before startDate
Below I have an example of my code, however I have no idea how i could compare the two fields within the test

```
  const defaultDates = {
    startDate: '20-09-2019',
    EndDate: '19-09-2020'
  };

  const dates = Object.assign(defaultDates, fields);

  cy.pickDate('startDate', dates.startDate);
  cy.pickDate('EndDate', dates.EndDate);
};
```

Comment: at the moment you don't have any dates, you've only got a couple strings that represent dates - you're gonna need to convert those strings to javascript date objects, which you can then compare

Comment: It's not clear what component library you're using, so we can't know how to get dates out of the component, or how those dates are represented (as strings or Dates). Please [edit] your question with more information about your environment and what you're testing.

Comment: can you provide more information on what cy.pickDate() returned?